# why is my API returning a JSON inside of an XML node?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

All I want to do is return a JSON to the browser.

This is what gets returned right now -- it's the JSON but it's inside a string. How do I return just a JSON?

[image]

And here's my code:

```
namespace ...Controllers
{
    public class NotificationsController : ApiController
    {
        public string getNotifications(int id)
        {
            var bo = new HomeBO();
            var list = bo.GetNotificationsForUser(id);
            var notificationTreeNodes = (from GBLNotifications n in list
                                         where n.NotificationCount != 0
                                         select new NotificationTreeNode(n)).ToList();
            List<Node> lOfNodes = new List<Node>();
            foreach (var notificationTreeNode in notificationTreeNodes)
            {
                Node nd = new Node();
                nd.notificationType = notificationTreeNode.NotificationNode.NotificationType + " " + "(" + notificationTreeNode.NotificationNode.NotificationCount + ")";
                var notificationList = bo.GetNotificationsForUser(id, notificationTreeNode.NotificationNode.NotificationTypeId).Cast<GBLNotifications>().ToList();
                List<string> notificationDescriptions = new List<string>();
                foreach (var item in notificationList)
                {
                    notificationDescriptions.Add(item.NotificationDescription);
                }
                nd.notifications = notificationDescriptions;
                lOfNodes.Add(nd);
            }
            var oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(lOfNodes);
            return sJSON;
        }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public string notificationType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<string> notifications
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to do a GET with the URL for this controller, Fiddler is not showing anything under JSON.

Anyone know what the issue is here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you return JSON:

```
var oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(lOfNodes);
return sJSON;
```

Instead of doing this you should just return `lOfNodes` (and change the return value to `List<Node>`) and rely on the built-in Content Negotiation.

Web API will return XML or JSON depending on the `Accept` header. If you need other formats, you could write you own formatter easily.

EDIT:

Since you are having some problems with Kendo UI (I don't know how the request are made) it might help to remove the XML formatter explicit. See [this post](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/) for an example.

Comment: the problem is that I need to return a JSON so I can use it in my KendoUI TreeView...

Comment: Web API will handle this for you depending on the "Accept" header.

Comment: I reverted it back to what I had which is exactly what you told me to do. but im having a hard time getting kendo ui to work... are you any good with it? im able to display the parent items but not the children :(

Comment: I am familiar with Web API, but not with Kendo UI.